# Completely remove and reinstall Foreman RHEL 6

Tags: redhat

I have a RHEL 6 host I inherited on which I need to install Foreman stable. It previously had [Red Hat's OpenStack "Technology Preview"](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_OpenStack/3/html/Deployment_Guide_Foreman_Technical_Preview/), which relied on Puppet 2.5 and was not useful for permanent use.

I needed remove the old Foreman and associated packages and install a new Foreman. With the caveat that I'm a debian person, I `yum remove` the openstack package, remove the associated repos and enable EPEL and the "optional" channel.

When I follow the instructions to download the foreman-installer and run it, the installer seems to download fine, but when doing a puppet run it errors out with missing components (passenger, selinux, etc.)

I'm stuck. Is there any good way to completely remove Foreman and reinstall it from scratch? The answer I got on #theforeman was "wipe the machine", which is not an option.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this besides wiping the machine?